# chewie and chewie_audio packages are showing error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am setting up flutter project but every time getting the below errors:

```
1 warning generated.
    ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:83:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding'.
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1451:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      const Scaffold({
            ^^^^^^^^
    ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:276:17: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
     - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
            context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieControllerProvider)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie_audio-1.0.0+1/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:101:51: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
    Try removing the extra positional arguments.
            context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieAudioControllerProvider)
                                                      ^

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8 Plus.
```

I have already tried stable channel and beta channels.

**chewie** is only showing in pubsec.lock file. Please let me know if anyone can give suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that You saved previous changed in pubspec.yaml and after that
try to run:

1. flutter pub get
2. flutter clean
3. flutter run

Comment: i did that many times but it's not working.

Comment: Can you provide me full code of your file where error occurs ?

Comment: It's old project I am only setting up on my system so I don't know how it comes.

Comment: The packages may be outdated, are sure to check www.pub.dev and search for your packages, the versions may be outdated

Comment: Updated all the packages but still getting the same issue.

Comment: It would be the best option to preview your full code file in order to see when the error occurs. Is there any way you can get it somehow ?

Comment: I downgraded the flutter version latest to 1.22.6 and platform :ios, '9.0' in Podfile. Finally it works. Also above commands format is wrong the order is 1. flutter clean  2. flutter pub get.  3. flutter run